# How to teach my dog to not be afraid of my air pump

Tags: dogs, fear

My dog is afraid of the manual air pump I use for pumping my bike's tires (when I carry it but especially when I operate it). How can I teach him that there's nothing to be afraid ? I've seen videos of dogs that love air pumps blowing at their faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dogs are often scared of things like that - but whenever they show fear, we try to show positive reinforcement. A few things to try:

1. Lure your dog to touch the air pump (when it is not blowing air) and give the dog treats/attention whenever it touches it.
2. When it gets a little bit more comfortable with it, show the air that can come out. (Don't blow it in the animal's face) But show that it can be kind of fun.
3. Make a little bit of a game out of using the air pump.

In general, I think dogs can love it or hate it. My dogs are tolerant but I don't think they will ever love it.